# NHibernate - Mapping custom reference types in legacy system

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am working on legacy system,and I'm in the process of porting it to nhibernate.

The system is based on generated "Entity" C# classes,
and a data access infrastructure which is based on wrapping cross-entity references in a special "Link" class. This was a misguided attempt to implement lazy-loading, which in practice harms more than it helps.

Example:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set;}
    public int Total {get; set;}
    public Link<Customer> Customer {get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Link<T>
{
   ... Snip ...
   public T Entity { get; private set;}
}
```

In the order table, the "Customer" column is a standard foreign key.

this means that in the entire system, any work with these "entities" takes the following form:

```
if (Order.Customer != null)
{
    if (Order.Customer.Entity != null)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

After much research, I couldn't find a method to map these classes in a way that will allow sane usage of nhibernate's querying capabilities.
The closest solution I found is the **IPropertyAccessor** interface, which will possibly solve my mapping problems, but won't play nice with queries.

A few notes:
1) Unfortunately, the main problem of the Link wrapper classes is here to stay, I can't remove it without rewriting the entire legacy infrastructure.
2) I Have full access to the code-generation templates, and can change the entity classes structure as I see fit. For example, to fix a different major issue I generated a poco-like interface for each entity:
    public interface IOrder
    {
        public ICustomer Customer {get; set;}
        ...
    }

```
public class Order : IOrder
{
    ...
    public Link<Customer> Customer {get; set;}
    ICustomer IOrder.Customer
    {
       (Adapting code here)
    } 
    ...
}
```

In short: any tips from NH gurus will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not able to comment, I will share this [link](http://ayende.com/blog/2951/nhibernate-and-generic-entities) that could help you to solve your problem, I think you migth have to map all posible uses of link, but you will have many limitations as this is not expected for NHibernate

Comment: Don't forget to share your updates of the current state of your problem :-)